# UISegmentedControl with two controller

Tags: iphone, uisegmentedcontrol

Hello I am making a UISegmentedControl with two segment. Clicking on either of the segments tab should bring up a controller which has a table view in it. I am able to get things done upto this point, but when I select a cell in my table I am suppose to push a new viewcontroller, I can see that

```
 - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

getting called, and it runs all the code as well, but I don't see the new view.

Basically the problem is the private view and the public view is not able to access any of the navigation properties.

Here is the screen shot of what I want to do

[image: Screen Shot]

Here are the codes

AppDelegate

```
UINavigationController *localNavigationController;
ManageSegmentedViewControl *manageSegmentedViewControl = [[ManageSegmentedViewControl alloc]init]];
localNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:pickUpDootController];
localNavigationController.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlack;
```

ManageSegmentedViewControl

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    PrivateViewController * controller1 = [[PrivateViewController alloc] init];
    PublicViewController * controller2 = [[PublicViewController alloc] init];


    self.segmentedViewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:controller1, controller2, nil];
   [controller1 release];
   [controller2 release];


   self.segmentedControl =
    [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Private",  @"Public", nil]];
   self.segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex = 0;
   self.segmentedControl.segmentedControlStyle = UISegmentedControlStylePlain;
   self.segmentedControl.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 44);

   [self.segmentedControl addTarget:self action:@selector(didChangeSegmentControl:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
   [self.view addSubview:self.segmentedControl];
   [self didChangeSegmentControl:self.segmentedControl]; // kick everything off
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
     [super viewWillAppear:animated];
     [self.activeViewController viewWillAppear:animated];
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    [self.activeViewController viewDidAppear:animated];
 }

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
    [self.activeViewController viewWillDisappear:animated];
 }

- (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidDisappear:animated];
    [self.activeViewController viewDidDisappear:animated];
 }

- (void)viewDidUnload{
       [super viewDidUnload];

 }


 #pragma mark -
 #pragma mark Segment control

 - (void)didChangeSegmentControl:(UISegmentedControl *)control {
       UIViewController* newCtl = [self.segmentedViewControllers objectAtIndex:control.selectedSegmentIndex];

       if(newCtl == activeViewController)
          return;
       if([activeViewController isViewLoaded]){
         [self.activeViewController viewWillDisappear:NO];
         [self.activeViewController.view removeFromSuperview];
         [self.activeViewController viewDidDisappear:NO];
       }
       if(newCtl != nil){
         activeViewController = newCtl;
         [self.activeViewController viewWillAppear:NO];
         [self.view addSubview:self.activeViewController.view];
         [self.activeViewController viewDidAppear:NO];

       }
}
```

How does my privateviewcontroller and publicviewcontroller become part of the navigationcontroller and access all the property of navigationcontroller

Comment: It sounded like you want to push a new view controller when the segmented control is changed, right?  But I'm confused how that relates to selecting the table cell.

Comment: no, i don't want to push, I have two view controller that will be shown when you select one of the segmented control, and my both view controller has a table view, so when you click on the cell, at that moment i want to push a new view controller on the stack, and that's what I am not able to find how to do.